# How to change the html tag data with if condition in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to change the machine name based on the IMEI number, getting an error while writing if condition inside the div.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <small>(Imei : @item.DeviceImei)</small>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    @if (item.DeviceImei==="868997035786332")
    {
        <small>(Machine : Power Complex)</small>
    }
    else
    {
    <small>(Machine:NA)</small>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: First of all you should replace `===` with `==`  in `@if (item.DeviceImei==="868997035786332")` line, it's server-side code not a javascript code and  what error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of your `if`. When you use an HTML tag, the Razor view engine will be off and you should use @ for your next C# code, in this situation, you should use this:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <small>(Imei : @item.DeviceImei)</small>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    @if (item.DeviceImei==="868997035786332")
    {
        <small>(Machine : Power Complex)</small>
    }
    @else
    {
    <small>(Machine:NA)</small>
    }
</div>
```